# WPF alignment of textbox and button within a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment

this is a rather simple question and its technically not that big of a deal but my OCD is tingling when i see this.
I have designed a basic WPF application and i cannot figure out why exactly the button and the textboxs are not alligning correctly as can be seen in this image(bottom right side):
[image: Check bottom right side]

This is the code responsible for it:

```
<Grid Margin="283,365.288,18,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Label Content="GUID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0.998,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22.96"/>
            <Label Content="UniqueID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,22.68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25.516" Width="63.297"/>
            <Label Content="Akt/GZ" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,48.196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25.516" Width="63.297"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23.958" Margin="63.297,0,0,49.754" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="125"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23.958" Margin="63.297,0,0,25.796" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="125"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23.958" Margin="63.297,0,0,1.558" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="125"/>
            <Button Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193.297,0.998,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60.703" Height="22.96"/>
            <Button Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193.297,25.236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60.703" Height="22.96"/>
            <Button Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193.297,49.194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60.703" Height="22.96"/>
            <CheckBox Content="07" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,5.498,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox Content="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="296.915,5.498,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox Content="07" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,29.736,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox Content="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="296.915,29.736,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox Content="07" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,53.694,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox Content="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="296.915,53.694,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
```

Either way I am not quite sure what causes it to... drift away for a bit. Also (in case someone asks) I am not sure why i used a Grid to group these objects, I googled on object groupings in WPF and i found some answers but the Grid and the Stackpanel seemed like the easiest to use, but the Stackpanel gave me even bigger headaches when aligning the content properly.
If you have some criticism regarding the imlpementation please feel free to do so, I have already ordered some books regardnig WPF design but I am more than happy and willing to listen to experienced devs and learn.

I apologize for the "noobish" question but I have spent the last 2 days fiddling around with the settings to no avail and wouldn't have come here and asked otherwise.

Thank you

Comment: http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

Comment: [WPF Tutorial : Layout-Panels-Containers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans)

In this case, grid is right choice. But you need to use Columns and Rows.

Comment: @ValeraScherbakov Thank you for the Link, reading it right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `Grid` layout in the wrong way.
Using `Margin` in `Grid` is not recommended, for many reasons (Performance, Stretching problems and so on)

The `Grid` layout allows you to set Rows and Columns and order your controls in a table.

You can read more about it here
http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

You first have to declare your rows and cols using `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` and then apply each control to it's row and column using the attribute `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`

reading the link I've attached will explain things better

Comment: Thank you very much Ron, will read after I have read Valeras link.

Guess I'll have to rewrite a couple of things :)